# textColorSecondary and textColorTertiary show up as the same under AppCompat light theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Steps to reproduce:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorTertiary"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Start the MainActivity and we get:
[image]

Use the layout inspector we read the current text color of the lower two TextViews to be the same value `-1979711488`, which corresponds to color hex `#8a000000`. I looked up the source code of Android and found that textColorSecondary is controlled by an alpha value defined in `colors_material.xml` as:

```
<item name="secondary_content_alpha_material_light" format="float" type="dimen">0.54</item>
```

which translates to `#8a0000000`. And textColorTertiary is defined explicitly to be `#8a0000000`. However, in my Android Studio 3.0.1, design panel, they show as three different colors:[image]

Is it true that both colors are defined the same? or what am I missing to properly use them?